# tmux report error on vi copy mode?

Tags: tmux

i have been using the same config for a long time

```
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
```

Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I start to receive this kind of error:

> /home/user/.tmux.conf:13: usage: bind-key [-cnr] [-T key-table] key
>   command [arguments]
>   [0/0]

Have you ever run into the same kind of problem?

```
tmux -V
tmux 2.6
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax has changed, and now requires `send-keys`, so:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send-keys -X copy-selection
```